# Kill task remote on busy Windows 10 machine

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

I have a windows 10 machine (far away) running numerical computations that I administrate using mstsc.exe (MS Remote Desktop).

I started two computations this morning, one of which I gave "High" priority because I want it comleted asap.

Directly after changing the priority in task manager my RDP session froze. 
The jobs take several hours (several days) and at this point I would prefer to stop them. Then I can restart them with a normal priority and I can still use remote administration to view intermediate results.

I tried:

```
taskkill /s XX.XXX.XXX.XX /u Username /p Password  /FI "IMAGENAME eq compute0.exe"
```

I get:
ERROR: The RPC server is unavailable.

When I try a new RDP session it will go through all the normal steps very slowly, there is a windows 10 loading screen but then it will display a completely black screen with cursor and it will timeout shortly after.

How can I stop the task? I wouldnt mind if the machine needs to be restarted, but it is nearly 1000KM from where I am now.

Comment: You don't have BMC/KVM access?  If this is Windows, have you tried a WMI/PowerShell approach?

Comment: No KVM, wmic also responds with "Description = The RPC server is unavailable."

Comment: Assuming that you're accessing this machine via the internet and not using a VPN connection to the remote network, you're not going to be able to access the machine via RPC. You're going to have to have someone get console access to this machine to kill the processes or manually power cycle the machine for you.